# CNN without actuators

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning

After training CNNs without actuators, I have an idea to compare their weights with each other using image mirroring. I am looking for ideas about reality perception of CNNs in this way.

What might CNN models need to act in next situation? How I can understanding that this is not problemomatic?

*The question should be accepted philologic. This is important for finding short way algorithms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: CNN's do not have anything to do with actuation. They transform input in a specific way. Most CNN's do not have actuators. They might be used in systems that have actuators. Or used as a subcomponent of a RL algorithm that actually is tasked with making decisions. But lacking actuation does not affect a CNN or change them in a fundamental way. I think you need to re-phrase this question for additional clarity or revisit your understanding of CNNs. What do you mean by actuator?

Comment: Tethering that provide the output.  Connection points are required for inputs and outputs as a result.  I do not equate the operation of a network model without output tethering with sending output weights to the GC.